# Populating 2D-Array

Tags: c++, arrays

- Hi, i am trying to create an array in C++ specifically to populate a 2D-Array with the user input and then order it into Ascending and Descending.
- So some of this could was given by a fellow friend whilst the rest i created, i am not sure what i am doing wrong..
- I have been able to output a statically generated Array but not been able to store with the input from the user.

**- To me the code makes sense but i do not know how to store the user input into the array, Could anyone help/emphasize a bit? Since i am not sure how to populate the 2D array or greatly confident on C++.**

```
int main ()
{

    int array[6][5];
    int i, j, swapx, swapy;

    printf("Initial array \n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf ("{%d, %d}", array[0][i], array [1][i]);
        if(i != (N - 1)){
            printf(", ");
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (N - 1); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < (N - i - 1); j++)
        {
            if(array[0][j] > array[0][j+1]){
                swapx = array[0][j];
                swapy = array[1][j];
                array[0][j] = array[0][j+1];
                array[1][j] = array[1][j+1];
                array[0][j+i] = swapx;
                array[1][j+1] = swapy;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nSorted Array: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf ("{%d, %d}", array[0][i], array [1][i]);
        if(i != (N - 1)){
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The absence of a question mark is a god indicator that you did not actually *ask a question*. What exactly is the problem? Do you get errors? Do you have input and output that is unexpected?

Comment: In your first loop, why are you printing out the value of the array before it's filled with any data?  You do know that `printf` outputs values, right?

Comment: It seems you want a `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`, then you could call `std::sort` on that `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through each row and then column of the 2D array and use `std::cin` to set the columns values via input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int arr[2][2];
    std::cout << "Enter four values: ";

    //loop through each row
    for (auto& row : arr) {
        //loop through each column
        for (auto& col : row) {
            std::cin >> col;
            //obtain input
        }
    }

    for (auto& row : arr) {
        for (auto& col : row) {
            std::cout << col << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    //do what you want with the array
}
```

Comment: Is this eligible for Dev C++? As it mentions to me that '#include <restream>' no such file or directory

Comment: @Morph It's <iostream>. What version of Dev C++ (or better, what version of the compiler) do you have? Ranged for loops need a C++11 compliant compiler.